# Why am I getting F# error FS0039: The namespace or module 'Http' is not defined

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-data

In Visual Studio 2015 and 2017, I'm trying out the Http class from several F# examples in FSharp Interactive, and I keep getting:

> error FS0039: The namespace or module 'Http' is not defined

Here's the sample:

```
open FSharp.Data
let response = Http.RequestString("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie", silentHttpErrors = true)
```

This is clearly due to the version of FSharp.Data. Is there a way to specify the correct version for FSharp Interactive? What version of FSharp.Data contains the Http module?

Comment: Have you referenced the library?

Comment: does my use of `open FSharp.Data` reference an out of date version? How do I reference the up to date FSharp.Data.dll from the FSharp interactive

Comment: you need to install FSharp.Data via nuget or paket. It will go inside a packages subfolder in your projects/solutions folder. Then either you reference in the fsproj file (for fs files) or your reference via `#r path/to/Fsharp/Data/Dll` in the fsx file. After that you can open it. Probably you are missing one of these steps. Because of the old (v 3) type providers, there is a global FSharp.Data namespace. You might be just opening that. But you actually need to nuget this package. Ping me in F# chat or slack if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, I put together a script to install Paket, intitialise it and then optionally install the dependencies whenever the script was run.

```
/// install.paket.fsx
open System
open System.IO

printfn "Initialising..."
Environment.CurrentDirectory <- __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__
// invisibly run a command (paket.exe in this case)
let init paket =
    let psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(paket)
    psi.Arguments <- "init"
    psi.UseShellExecute <- false
    let p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi)
    p.WaitForExit()
    p.ExitCode

if not (File.Exists "paket.exe") then
    printfn "installing paket"
    let url = "http://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/stable"
    use wc = new Net.WebClient()
    let tmp = Path.GetTempFileName()
    let stable = wc.DownloadString(url)
    wc.DownloadFile(stable, tmp)
    File.Move(tmp,Path.GetFileName stable)
    printfn "paket installed"
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
    printfn "initialising paket"
    init "paket.exe" |> ignore
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
    printfn "paket initialised"
else
    printfn "paket already exists"

/// install.dependencies.fsx

open System.IO
printfn "Installing dependencies"
System.Environment.CurrentDirectory <- __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__
#r "paket.exe"

open Paket
let dependencies = Paket.Dependencies.Locate(__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__)

printfn "%s" dependencies.DependenciesFile

if not (File.Exists "packages/Newtonsoft.Json/lib/net40/Newtonsoft.Json.dll") then
    printfn "installing nuget depenencies"
    // either use the dependencies.Install to add dependencies in the paket.dependencies file
    //dependencies.Install true |> ignore
    // or install them by name
    // I remove the existing versions
    dependencies.Remove "FSharp.Data"
    dependencies.Remove "Newtonsoft.Json 8.0.3"
    // then add them (because I'm pedantic about the way the dependencies file looks)
    dependencies.Add "FSharp.Data"
    dependencies.Add "Newtonsoft.Json 8.0.3"
    printfn "nuget depenencies installed"
else
    printfn "nuget depenencies already exist"

printfn "Dependencies installed"
```

Note the use of 8.0.3 for Newtonsoft.Json, The latest version brings over 20 additional dependencies, so I've found a nice old version that's very self contained. You may leave the version number out if you want the latest.

Then, I use these scripts in a shared utilities.fsx for reusable functionality

```
System.Environment.CurrentDirectory <- __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__
#load "install.paket.fsx"
#load "install.dependencies.fsx"

#r "packages/fsharp.data/lib/net40/fsharp.data.dll"
#r "packages/Newtonsoft.Json/lib/net40/Newtonsoft.Json.dll"

open FSharp.Data
open FSharp.Data.HtmlAttribute
open FSharp.Data.HtmlNode
open FSharp.Data.HttpRequestHeaders
open Newtonsoft.Json
open System.Net
open System.IO
// utilities like authentication, Http requests and JSON (de)serialization
```

Finally, I reference the whole lot in my target script by just loading utilities:

```
System.Environment.CurrentDirectory <- __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__
#load "utilities.fsx"
open Utilities
```

which takes care of all the dependencies. These can be run from Visual studio with the `Alt` + `Enter` key combination or from the command line with `fsi.exe MyScript.fsx`

Answer (score -1):

I know it is pretty old, but, via Visual Studio, cannot be as easy as just going to Solution Explorer, drill down until you find the node "Packages" under your project, right-click and select "Manage NuGet packages...", then just select FSharp.Data:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kvFA.png)