# F# asynchronous HTTP request - parse JSON response

Tags: swift, rest, asynchronous, f#, http-post

I'm trying to use the following snippet of `F#` to send an asynchronous POST request to Firebase: in particular the following operation, which allows for anonymous sign in:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-sign-in-anonymously

```
    let makePostRequest (url : string) (requestBody : string) = 
    let req = WebRequest.CreateHttp url
    req.CookieContainer <- new CookieContainer()
    req.Method <- "POST"
    req.ProtocolVersion <- HttpVersion.Version10
    let postBytes = requestBody |> System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes
    req.ContentLength <- postBytes.LongLength
    req.ContentType <- "application/xml; charset=utf-8"
    async{
        use! reqStream = req.GetRequestStreamAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
        do! reqStream.WriteAsync(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length) |> Async.AwaitIAsyncResult |> Async.Ignore
        reqStream.Close()
        use! res = req.AsyncGetResponse() 
        use stream = res.GetResponseStream()
        use reader = new StreamReader(stream)
        let! rdata = reader.ReadToEndAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask        
        return rdata
    }
```

I am calling it as follows:

```
    let url = "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    let data = "returnSecureToken=true"
    makePostRequest url data
```

I'm very new to `F#` and a bit confused as to how this works. How can I obtain the JSON response from this request? How will I know when this is complete? Will this block the UI on the main thread? What I am doing is translating the following block of Swift code:

```
 Auth.auth().signInAnonymously(completion: { (user, error) in

        if let err = error {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

    })
```

Here everything makes sense to me as we have a completion block which gets called after the method is done executing, and we know that the `user` variable will contain the response obtained from the server, it makes much less sense to me in F#.

UPDATE:

Following the suggestions in the comments, I have referenced F# Data: HTTP Utilities and created the following code snippet:

```
let url = "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=XXXXXXXXXXXX"
Http.RequestString
    ( url, 
      headers = [ ContentType HttpContentTypes.Json ],
      body = TextRequest """ {"returnSecureToken": true} """)
```

However this produces the error `The value, namespace, type or module Http is not defined`

UPDATE 2: 
I have settled for the following code:

```
let fetchUrl callback url (requestBody : string) =        
    let req = WebRequest.Create(Uri(url)) 
    req.Method <- "POST"
    let postBytes = requestBody |> System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes
    req.ContentLength <- postBytes.LongLength
    req.ContentType <- "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    let reqStream = req.GetRequestStream() 
    reqStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
    reqStream.Close()

    use resp = req.GetResponse() 
    use stream = resp.GetResponseStream() 
    use reader = new IO.StreamReader(stream) 
    callback reader url

let myCallback (reader:IO.StreamReader) url = 
    let html = reader.ReadToEnd()
    let html1000 = html.Substring(0,1000)
    printfn "Downloaded %s. First 1000 is %s" url html1000
    html      // return all the html


let openLandlord ()  =
    let url = "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    let requestBody = """ {"returnSecureToken": true} """
    fetchUrl myCallback url requestBody
```

following the example here:

https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/fvsc-download/

however when I call the `openLandlord` function here:

```
 override x.ViewDidLoad () =
    base.ViewDidLoad ()
    openLandlord ()
```

I get the following error:

This expression was expected to have type uint but here has type string.

[image]

Errors:

1. Incomplete structured construct at or before this point in binding.
2. The value of constructor request is not defined.
3. Unexpected keyword match in member definition.
4. The value, namespace, type or module Response is not defined.
5. Unexpected identified in member definition.

Comment: Your question is too broad. And you compare one high-level API with another low-level API. If you want, you can delegate request processing to the library. For example, FSharp.Data has nice HTTP utilities: http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/Http.html

Comment: I don't think it is too broad...all I want to do is send an HTTP POST request asynchronously without blocking the UI, and then obtain the JSON response of this request in a closure block (or something equivalent to it). I tried using Http.fs however this won't install for xamarinios apparently

Comment: Sorry, I just read "a bit confused as to how this works" as something encouraging me to explain the code in details which requires too broad answer. If you just want to get JSON from the response data, you can either use F#-specific JSON type provider from FSharp.Data or .NET Newtonsoft.JSON. There are plenty examples for both. UI thread will be fine if you use asynchronous operations.

Comment: No worries @AlexAtNet, can you please have a look at the edit? I have tried following the POST example from the FSharp.Data you have linked

Comment: You can use AsyncRequestString to get the string asynchronously. To import Http into the scope you can use "open FSharp.Data" at the beginning of the code file (it is like import in Swift).

Comment: @AlexAtNet I do have open FSharp.Data already...do you think it is an issue related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46277357/why-am-i-getting-f-error-fs0039-the-namespace-or-module-http-is-not-defined ...regarding the AsyncRequestString, how would I know when the async is done executing (the closure structure in Swift)...could you post a small snippet as an answer showing me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following code:

```
open System
open System.Net
open FSharp.Data

type Response = JsonProvider<""" { "name":"John", "age":94 } """>

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
  let request () =
    async {
      let url = "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=XXXXXXXXXXXX"
      return! Http.AsyncRequestString
        ( url,
          headers = [ "Content-Type", HttpContentTypes.Json ],
          body = TextRequest """ {"returnSecureToken": true} """ )
    } |>  Async.Catch
  let result = request ()
               |> Async.RunSynchronously
  match result with
  | Choice1Of2 text -> let json = Response.Parse text
                       printfn "name: %A" json.Name   
  | Choice2Of2 e -> printfn "request failed: %A" e
  0 // return an integer exit code
```

If type provides are not working with your setup, this may help: https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/3303

Replace sample JSON with what is expected from the service.

Comment: I know, the problem is I can't get your code to work in the iOS setting I have to build this in, further to that I'm very new to F# and don't really understand the control flow in your code and how to use it, I don't want to simply copy paste something I won't be able to understand... whereas that code is much more straightforward and I understand how it works.

Comment: I think that `type` statement should be moved out of `let`, one level up.

Comment: Yeah that helped, the problem is I still cannot use the FSharp.Data... even though I added it through the packet manager and added the open statement, it doesn't seem to be recognised. Is there a way to do this without using FSharp.Data?

Comment: Have you tried to add fsc.props to enable type providers? Also you can us e Newtonsoft.Json instead, which is de facto standard for JSON in .net.

Comment: @AlexNetkachov, It seems, you missed a comma after formatting string: `printfn "name: %A" json.Name`