# Fsharp.Data HttpRequestBody getting 'The mandatory 'grant_type' parameter is missing'

Tags: f#, httprequest, f#-data

I am using Fsharp.Data to male HttpRequests.
I want to get my token from a URL.
I tried (from here [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47995053/f-asynchronous-http-request-parse-json-response)

```
let request () =
    async {
      let url = tokenUrl
      return! Http.AsyncRequestString
        ( url,
          headers = [ ContentType HttpContentTypes.FormValues;
           Origin "https://www....;
           Referer "https://www.../login";
           Accept "application/json, text/plain, */*"],
          body = TextRequest """ {"grant_type": "password",
                            "password": "xxx",
                            "username": "y@..."} """ )
    } |>  Async.Catch
```

But I get

> 'The mandatory 'grant_type' parameter is missing'

I used the same arguments with Python, where it worked.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: What happens if you change your content type to `HttpContentTypes.Json` since you're passing Json in the body?

Comment: @JasonDown: Then I get  `'Content-Type' header is not valid.`

Comment: Did you see my answer below? You shouldn't be sending the body as JSON.

Comment: Yes, but I was struggling with the right syntax, before it worked. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you are sending the body as JSON, when [it should be form values](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/06/29/what-is-the-oauth2-password-grant):

```
body =
    FormValues [
        "grant_type", "password"
        "password", "xxx"
        "username", "y@..."
    ]
```

I haven't tested this, though.

Comment: Thanks. Put me in the right direction. `body = FormValues ["grant_type", "password";                          "password","xxxxx; "username", "y@.....]` was the solution. I am a F# beginner, so the seq format was my biggest challenge....

Comment: You can leave out the semi-colons if you put each entry on a separate line.